# Ionic 3 Sqlite Returning Null

Tags: javascript, sqlite, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to read out of my Sqlite database in Ionic 3 but the returned value is always null. If I `console.log(data.rows.item(0).token)` in the method then it logs the correct value to the console but doesn't return the correct value to the calling code.

This is the method I am using to get the token:

```
getToken() {
    //Open database
    this.openCreateDatabase()
      .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
        //Execute select
        db.executeSql("SELECT token FROM Token WHERE id = 1", [])
          .then((data) => {
            //Get and return the token
            return data.rows.item(0).token;
          })
          .catch((e) => {
            //Log any errors
            console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
            return null;
          })
      });
  }
```

The calling code is simply:

```
ionViewDidEnter(){
  console.log(this.sql.getToken());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[IftekharDani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2442968/iftekhardani) pointed me in the right direction by mentioning promises, although his solution didn't work directly it helped me develop one that did. The code I ended up with is as follows:

```
getToken() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.openCreateDatabase()
        .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
          db.executeSql("SELECT * FROM Token WHERE id = 1", [])
            .then((data) => {
              let tokenValues = [];
              if (data.rows.length > 0) {
                for (let i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
                  tokenValues.push(data.rows.item(i).token);
                }
              }
              resolve(tokenValues);
            }, (error) => {
              reject(error);
            })
        });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

> For getting token you need to make getToken as `Promise`.

**Add return before `openCreateDatabase`;**

```
getToken() {
    //Open database
    //
    return this.openCreateDatabase()
      .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
        //Execute select
        db.executeSql("SELECT token FROM Token WHERE id = 1", [])
          .then((data) => {
            //Get and return the token
            return data.rows.item(0).token;
          })
          .catch((e) => {
            //Log any errors
            console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
            return null;
          })
      });
  }
```

**Change `ionViewDidEnter` with :**

**1.async await**

```
async ionViewDidEnter(){
 let token = await this.sql.getToken();
  console.log(token);
}
```

**2. Or `Then`**

```
ionViewDidEnter(){
     this.sql.getToken().then(token => {
console.log(token)
     })
    .....
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this - didn't work directly but I did convert my methods to Promises and they now work.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to create a method local variable or a js file global variable and return that one. Something like this:

```
getToken() {
//Open database
this.openCreateDatabase()
  .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
    //Execute select
    db.executeSql("SELECT token FROM Token WHERE id = 1", [])
      .then((data) => {
        //Get and return the token
        let val = data.rows.item(0).token;
        return val;
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        //Log any errors
        console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
        return null;
      })
  });
  }
```

Tell us if that works.

Comment: Unfortunately still returns null

Comment: From where you call the getToken() method? What is your code files structure?